# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este pie de página?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estoy usando Bootstrap 3.3.7. Un mal uso del CSS ocasiona problemas en ciertas páginas al hacer *scroll-down*, tal como a continuación.

Página de inicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ningun problema con el pie de página, ahora vayamos a la zona de administradores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se puede reproducir el error.

Por más que intento, no hay solución. He buscado todo tipo de **footers** y códigos de CSS; el problema persiste.

**Codigo Utilizado/Actual/Fallido**:

```
 <style>
 footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
 }
 </style>
 <footer>
  <small class="text-muted"><a href="{{ route('terms') }}">Terms</a> • <a href="{{ route('privacy') }}">Privacy</a> • <a href="{{ route('status') }}">Status</a></small>
 </footer>
```

RESULTADO ESPERADO: El pie de página debiese colocarse **siempre** al final de la página. En el caso 1, la página no puede hacerse *scroll-down* la segunda es reproducible.

Comment: estas agregando mas contenido abajo del footer?

Comment: @Luis Fernando No...

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el código de la segunda página para que podamos reproducir el error?

Answer (score 4):

En el estilo de la clase footer, en vez de utilizar **absolute**

```
position: absolute;
```

utiliza **fixed**

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar **position: fixed** y **width 100%**; con **bottom: 0** tranquilamente puedes fijarlo en la parte inferior.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
footer {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 background-color: #efefef;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Hola Yerson. Procura esxplicar mejor la respuesta. Lee [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por el feedback. Asi lo haré :)